# a count-down component with useEffect not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm learning to react hooks. I write a count-down component. `useEffect` makes me confused.
when the timer turns to 00:00, it can't show 00:00, just turn to 00:10. anyone can help?
below is a demo.

[count-down](https://codesandbox.io/embed/new-sunset-vw1wu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)
[image]

```
export default function App() {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(dayjs().minute(0).second(10));
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(true);

  const handleReset = () => {
    setStatus(true);
    setTimer(dayjs().minute(0).second(10));
  };
  const handleStartStop = () => {
    setStatus((pre) => !pre);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimer((pre) => {
      if (pre.format("mm:ss") === "00:00") {
        return dayjs().minute(0).second(10);
      }
      return pre;
    });
  }, [timer]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!status) {
      const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        setTimer((pre) => {
          return pre.subtract(1, "second");
        });
      }, 1000);
      return () => {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      };
    }
  }, [status]);

  return (
    <>
      <div id="timer-label">
        count down
        <div id="time-left">{timer.format("mm:ss")}</div>
        <div>
          <button id="start_stop" onClick={() => handleStartStop()}>
            {status ? "start" : "stop"}
          </button>
          <button id="reset" onClick={handleReset}>
            reset
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I just ran your sandbox, the countdown hit "00:00" and then started over at "00:10". Can you clarify what the issue is? What is the expected result? If you are trying to avoid hitting "00:00" then your condition should be `if (pre.format("mm:ss") === "00:01") {`.

Comment: Can you clarify more of yourr query?

Comment: I have changed my sandbox. I don't understand this version why not work as I expected. @AnilLoutombam

Comment: I see same behavior. Did anything change? From what I can tell your code is functioning as written. If you want it to do something else then you need to describe better what you are expecting.

Comment: Can you please be more specific,what is the issue

Comment: @DrewReese I add a gif and code. 00:01 turns to 00:10, 00:00 not display.

Comment: What changed from your initial sandbox? That hit double-zeros for me and now I see the same thing as you. I'm checking your code again, btw.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between the two versions. I think they should be have the same result. version 1, I write the `if (pre.format("mm:ss") === "00:00")``condition in one useEffect. version 2, the condition is in another useEffect that dependency timer.

Comment: your sandbox is working fine as expected it's hitting to 00:00

Comment: Ah, I see, so does this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/a-count-down-component-with-useeffect-not-working-as-expected-mxk5g) work as you are expecting? It hits "00:00".

Comment: I have changed my sandbox. I don't why your guy can not see the new version. I have added a gif and the code not working correctly.  00:01 turns to 00:10, 00:00 not display.

Comment: @DrewReese yes.it works. But I am confused, why use two `useEffect` not work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

When you split and use 2 `useEffect` hooks, it seems there is some clock skew between the effects and the timing of checking for "00:00" and resetting is out of sync with the interval.

```
useEffect(() => console.log('----- render -----'));

useEffect(() => {
  setTimer((pre) => {
    console.log('effect 2', pre.format("mm:ss"))
    if (pre.format("mm:ss") === "00:00") {
      return dayjs().minute(0).second(10);
    }
    return pre;
  });
}, [timer]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!status) {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setTimer((pre) => {
        console.log('effect 1', pre.format("mm:ss"))
        return pre.subtract(1, "second");
      });
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
  }
}, [status]);
```

These logs yield:

```
----- render ----- 
effect 1 00:10 
----- render ----- 
effect 2 00:09 
effect 1 00:09 
----- render ----- 
effect 2 00:08 
effect 1 00:08 
----- render ----- 
effect 2 00:07 
----- render ----- 
effect 2 00:06 
effect 1 00:07 
----- render ----- 
effect 2 00:05 
effect 1 00:06 
----- render ----- 
effect 2 00:04 
effect 1 00:05 
----- render ----- 
effect 2 00:03 
effect 1 00:04 
----- render ----- 
effect 2 00:02 
effect 1 00:03 
----- render ----- 
effect 2 00:01 
effect 1 00:02 
----- render ----- 
effect 2 00:00  // <-- this one is also not in sync
----- render ----- 
effect 2 00:10  // <-- immediately reset 
effect 1 00:01
```

This issue and skew is resolved by placing all the logic in a single `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!status) {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setTimer((pre) => {
        if (pre.format("mm:ss") === "00:00") {
          return dayjs().minute(0).second(10);
        }
        return pre.subtract(1, "second");
      });
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
  }
}, [status]);
```

[image: Edit a-count-down-component-with-useeffect-not-working-as-expected]

Answer (score 0):

Every time the timer hit 00:00 you immediately change it to 00:10 on the first useEffect without waiting 1000ms

if you want to display 00:00 you can remove the upper useEffect and check in the interval if you hit 00:00

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import dayjs from "dayjs";

export default function App() {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(dayjs().minute(0).second(10));
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(true);

  const handleReset = () => {
    setStatus(true);
    setTimer(dayjs().minute(0).second(10));
  };
  const handleStartStop = () => {
    setStatus((pre) => !pre);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!status) {
      const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        setTimer((pre) => {
          if (pre.format("mm:ss") === "00:00")
            return dayjs().minute(0).second(10);
          return pre.subtract(1, "second");
        });
      }, 1000);
      return () => {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      };
    }
  }, [status]);

  return (
    <>
      <div id="timer-label">
        count down
        <div id="time-left">{timer.format("mm:ss")}</div>
        <div>
          <button id="start_stop" onClick={() => handleStartStop()}>
            {status ? "start" : "stop"}
          </button>
          <button id="reset" onClick={handleReset}>
            reset
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```